# API request from UI is giving "Provided data is not of type bytes" when i switched to python3

Tags: api, flask, python-3.7

While migrating code from python2.7 to 3.7, I am facing below issue.
When I hit any request from UI like below.

[image]

When I look into the logs. I am able to print response json prior to return statement followed by 500 error. Below is my code snippet.

```
@app.route('/policy_count',methods=['GET'])
def wanhealth_policies()
    response = {'total': 25, 'offset':10}
    response = jsonify(status='success', result=response)
    print("RESPONSE:::::::::",response)
    return response
```

*ERROR:webapp_sa_wh:Exception on /policy_count [GET]

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "home/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app

    response = self.full_dispatch_request()

  File "home/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1479, in full_dispatch_request

    response = self.process_response(response)

  File "home/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1693, in process_response

    self.save_session(ctx.session, response)

  File "home/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 837, in save_session

    return self.session_interface.save_session(self, session, response)
  File "home/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_kvsession/**init**.py", line 193, in save_session

    store.put(session.sid_s, data, ttl)

  File "home/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/simplekv/decorator.py", line 87, in put

    self._dstore.put(self._map_key(key), *args, **kwargs))

  File "home/ENV/lib/python3.7/site-packages/simplekv/**init**.py", line 424, in put

    raise IOError("Provided data is not of type bytes")

OSError: Provided data is not of type bytes

WARNING:root:Sending error response: , data: b'{"error": "Provided data is not of type bytes", "status_code": 500}'*

OSError: Provided data is not of type bytes
WARNING:root:Sending error response: , data: b'{"error": "Provided data is not of type bytes", "status_code": 500}'
{address space usage: 581894144 bytes/554MB} {rss usage: 120606720 bytes/115MB} [pid: 6936|app: 0|req: 1/1] 10.2.0.1 () {60 vars in 1391 bytes} [Thu Mar 26 12:28:45 2020] GET /policy_count => generated 67 bytes in 452 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 90 bytes (1 switches on core 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar issue when I was migrating from Python 2.7 to Python 3.7 for a Flask Application. 
Flask-KVSession uses simplekv python package for storing session data on a variety of backend, and for version **Flask-KVSession=0.6.2**, the existing installed simplekv was not fully compatible with Python 3. Installing **simplekv==0.9.3** after installing Flask-KVSession resolved the issue.